# Can i print return array data without any handler file in ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, action, filehandler

Ajax gets return array data and prints the particular position to print out with a foreach loop.
But without any third file, it is possible?

I have all array data in the third file and all data to return an ajax and print that id through in php file.

My all return data associative array.

/* Handler file */

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
  echo '<li>' . $d['name'] . '</li>';
}
```

/* ajax file */

```
function (data) {
   $('#id').html(data);
}
```

Comment: this is way too broad. You haven't produced any source code which makes me think you haven't tried anything

Comment: Can you share more details on this?

Comment: I have tried.Response data get array but without any third file i have not printed any data because response data is an array and without foreach loop I cannot display a list of data

Comment: show the code.. edit your question and copy paste your code

Comment: That's not enough code to demonstrate anything, and your description of the problem is very unclear. Does your code work, or not? What exactly is it that you want us to help with?